# data does not shows inside recycleView with serializable, app crush - Java

Tags: android, serialization, android-recyclerview

I have a recycleView that does not shows the data sent from 1 activity to another with a serializable method.
What I could probably get wrong?
Without the recycleView, i am able to get the data, but only 1 string.
So, because i need multiply strings, I tought to put the strings inside the recycleView.
But i get this error:

```
2022-05-26 07:50:26.528 13686-13686/? E/no.crocesandre: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2022-05-26 07:50:26.529 13686-13686/? W/no.crocesandre: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2022-05-26 07:50:26.821 13686-13719/g.bruno.crocesandrea D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
2022-05-26 07:50:26.822 13686-13719/g.bruno.crocesandrea W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)

2022-05-26 07:50:26.996 13686-13686/g.bruno.crocesandrea W/no.crocesandre: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
```

**My Activity**

```
public class ResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView rcView;
ResultListAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);



    if(getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().hasExtra(CalculatorActivity.LIST_KEY)){
        ArrayList<CalculatorItemModel> arrayList = (ArrayList<CalculatorItemModel>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(CalculatorActivity.LIST_KEY);

        rcView = findViewById(R.id.rv_result);
        rcView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rcView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new ResultListAdapter(arrayList);
        rcView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

I want to add my ResultAdapter class, where I use the same `model class` "CalculatorItemModel", to better understand where could be the problem:

```
public class ResultListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ResultListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<CalculatorItemModel> mList;

public ResultListAdapter(ArrayList<CalculatorItemModel> mList) {
    this.mList = mList ;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.result_adapter_layout,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view1);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(mList.get(position).getIngName());
    holder.textView2.setText(mList.get(position).getIngQuantity());

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(mList == null){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return mList.size();
    }
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView, textView2;


    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
         textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTextResult);
         textView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTxResult2);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: that stack trace doesn't seem to be relevant to the crash, perhaps try looking for another cause

Comment: Thanks for the help. So, now everything works fine! I can receive the data. The only problem is that the recycleView create 1 activity UI for each string. So, if i input 2 different strings, it will not create a list. I can see that because when i click on the back button, it swipe back all the strings I entered. That it's quite weird, i never experienced it. However, Layout xml file it's seems fine. The Linear layout has ```android:layout_height="wrap_content"```